# Помощь новичку с кодом

Tags: ассемблер

Передо мной стояла задача, пользуясь интернет-ресурсами написать и запустить код для выведения результат вычислений по формуле. Числа B, C, D, даны в dec. A = B - C + 1.
B = 45, C = 10, D = 1.

```
 .model small ; тип данных?

.data ; набор данных
 B dw 45 ; в какой системе они здесь обычно указываються, 
 C dw 10
 D dw 1
 result dw ?,'$' ; ? - мы не знаем еще значения, и что делает $? читал, что это первый символ полученный?

.code ; сегмент кода
        mov ax, @data ; не знаем сдвиг 
        mov ds, ax ; сдвиг равен будет какому-то значению
        mov ax, B 
        sub ax, C 
        inc ax
        mov di, offset result ; что здесь толком происходит
        mov [di], ax ; что здесь толком происходит

        mov ah, 09h ; не понимаю, во многих вроде функция вывода
        mov dx, offset result ; 
        int 21h ; interrupting

        mov ah, 4ch ; не понимаю
        int 21h
        end
```

Короче вышел бред, сами видите. Только не кричите сразу "фу", а помогите с кодом. Это первая попытка самостоятельного, насколько это может быть, написания .exe кода.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54790/discussion-on-question-by-muscled-boy----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .model small ; тип данных?

.data ; набор данных
 B dw 45 ; значения в десятичной системе, шестнадецитичные писались бы с h на конце
 C dw 10 ; переменные двубайтные - dw (word)
 D dw 1
 result db ?,?,?,?,?,'$' ; место для результата, так как нам буден нужна
 ; человекочитаемая строка то она может состоять максимум из 5 байт данных
 ; (максимальное 2х байтное число 65535) и знак $ отмечающий конец печатаемой строки
 ; для функции 9 прерывания 21h

.code ; сегмент кода
        mov ax, @data ; помещаем в регистр ax адрес сегмента памяти, где лежат наши данные 
        mov ds, ax ; копируем значение из ax в регистр сегмента данных
                   ; когда мы будем писать mov ax,B на самом деле будет подразумеваться
                   ; mov ax,ds:[offset B], т.е. все переменные в коде адресуются относительно 
                   ; регистра ds и он должен содержать корректное значение
                   ; mov ds,@data мы написать не могли, т.к. в ds нельзя заносить
                   ; непосредственные значения, поэтому для пересылки мы пользовались ax
        mov ax, B  ; ax=B
        sub ax, C  ; ax=ax-C
        inc ax     ; ax++

; ---------- певод в десятичное ASCII
        MOV     CX,0010        ;Фактор деления
        LEA     SI,result+4    ;Адрес последнего выводимого символа
С20:
        CMP     AХ,0010        ;Значение меньше  10?
        JB      С30            ; Да - выйти
        XOR     DX,DX          ;Очистить часть частного
        DIV     CX             ;Разделить на 10
        OR      DL,30H         ;Делаем из байта 0-9 символ '0'-'9'
        MOV     [SI],DL        ;Записать ASCII-символ
        DEC     SI             ;Уменьшить адрес символа
        JMP     С20
C30:
        OR      AL,30H         ;Превратить поcл. частное в символ
        MOV     [SI],AL        ;3аписать символ
;---------------------------------
        mov ah, 09h   ; ah-фунция прерывания 21h, 9=вывод на экран
        mov dx, si    ; в dx помещаем адрес первого выводимого символа
                      ; функция 9 21h требует адрес выводимой строки в ds:dx
        int 21h               ; вызов прерывания функций DOS (21h)

        mov ah, 4ch           ; ah-функция прерывания 21h, 4c=завершить программу
        int 21h               ; вызов прерывания функций DOS (21h)
        end
```

Полезные ссылки:

[функции прерывания 21h](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0026.php)

[Таблица ASCII символов](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь остается только разобраться со всем этим.

Comment: @MuscledBoy Да, и очень рекомендую серьезно к этому отнестись и изучить ассемблер и рядом лежащие темы. Даже если никогда больше ничего писать на нем не понадобится. Даже если это выходит за рамки текущего курса обучения. Ибо это дает  настоящее понимание машин, сильно помогающее при работе на любых языках программирования